# Data not written to H2 DB while testing with JUnit

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, junit

I'm trying to write a JUnit test for my Spring module, after seeing that my logic is working using SwaggerUI.

What happens, however, is that I miss some data in my H2 instance (used for the tests only), and I don't understand why.

This is what I'm doing:

*MyObjectController.java*

```
@PostMapping("/myobject")
public void save(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {  
    // Save and get id
    Integer id = service.save();
    URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(id).toUri();

    // Run async
    service.run(id); // At this stage, id = 1 because the insert completed correctly

    // Return id
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, location.toString());
}
```

*MyObjectService.java*

```
@Async
@Transactional
public void run(Integer id) throws Exception { // As above, id = 1 but this time data is not there!
    // Retrieve and run
    Optional<MyObject> myObject = myObjectDao.findById(id);
    if (!myObject.isPresent()) {
        throw new NotFound();
    }
    ...
}
```

`/myobject` endpoint is called using MockMVC, and once called it correctly returns the expected id.

If I place a breakpoint at the beginning of `service.run(Integer id)`, and I call `/myobject` using SwaggerUI, I can see that everything is fine, but this doesn't happen when running in JUnit.

Can you guys please help me with that?

Comment: is there a `@Transactional` annotation on the unit test (method)?

Comment: check your configurations in your test folder

Comment: @xerx593 tried both with and without it, same results.

Comment: @Gnk can you please be more specific?

Comment: ..thanks for the feedback, i suspected "automatic test tx rollback", but that seems no hit. Another suspect: Are you looking into the correct H2 (instance)? (maybe junit operates on another database than you suppose ... `jdbc:h2:mem:test`) ...You say, you use it for tests only - you must have some sort of test configuration/profiles...